# Cakephp jquery clickable text within clickable text block - code snippet added

Tags: jquery, cakephp, clickable

I display a text extendable, when I click on it,  it shows all the text.
When I click again, it shrinks.
It works fine.

But if I have  a link text inside  the text   ,  let's say www.google.com,    I cannot click on it.

Here is the generated code

```
<div class="messageWrapper">


        <img src="webroot\img\cake.icon.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> 

        <a href="/contest/users/view/11">toto2</a>

        Test  <a href="http://hotmail.com" rel=nofollow>http://hotmail.com</a> test on clickable text within clickable zone 

                </br></br>

  </div>
```

Is anyone has an idea?

Comment: No one can begin helping you without a code snippet.

Comment: You could wrap your logic in your shrink handler with something like `if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'a')`

Comment: Incidentally, `</br>` should just be `<br>` or `<br/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

I gave a class to each url zone of the text,  e.g:

```
<a href="http://hotmail.com"  class='insideLink' rel=nofollow>http://hotmail.com</a> test blablablab...
```

and I add the following jquery command in my script

```
$('.insideLink').click(function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```